# I need Qt TreeModel and View Implementation

Tags: qt5, qtreeview, qabstractitemmodel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Txdce.jpg)

I have list of signals in Qstringlist signal1, signal2 --- so on..So i needs to put it in Under Signals as parent.. and using signalfilterproxymodel later i have to serach for child signals..

Needs to inherit class from QAbstractItem, and can please explain about 5 override functions parent, index, rowcount, columncount and data functions

Please help me out on this in qt tree view model, without using QTreewidgetItem

Comment: You should probably start by reading the [`Qt` model/view tutorial](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/modelview.html) and [model/view programming guide](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html).

Comment: If you have another question please create a new post.